# Mix the colours of two particle systems

Tags: c++, colors, openframeworks, particles, mixing

I'm trying to create two particle systems that are of different colours but when they interact their colours mix.

Does anyone have any good ideas of how to go about this?

I'm looking to do something similar to this -> vimeo(DOT)com/8693610

Comment: As far as I know, the STL doesn't ship with a particle engine.

Comment: What graphics library are you using (or aren't you?!)

Comment: I tried this with a flocking system with the colours changing based on the distance from the seeker, but I couldn't get the colours to stay the interpolated colour so if the colour of the flock was more than half way between the two colours it would stay the mixed colour however that didn't seem to work for some reason

Answer (score 0):

make them translucent, the colors automatically blend then... But what kind of question is this?

Comment: So the particle get's an average colour of all the colours around it, I don't think i want to make it translucent because I need solid colours for my simulation. But I guess that's an idea

Comment: Look at the video I suggested

Comment: Adjusting the alpha value from 1.0f to arround 0.75f would be enough which would not make them very transparent.

Comment: Yeah but that's not really the effect I'm looking for, thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

If you want the colors to mix when overlapping, but keep their alpha value, the `glBlendFunc` should do the trick for you.

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

This will make the colors blend, but not touch the alpha channel.